# How can I return error messages from SQL and use these error messages in my rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I know `unique: true` makes a column unique in Ruby on Rails migration

```
add_index :table_name, :column_name, unique: true
```

I also know that `validates :username, uniqueness: true` makes a column unique too.

I wanna just to use `add_index :table_name, :column_name, unique: true` for making my specific column unique.

If I only use from `add_index :table_name, :column_name, unique: true` without validation in any model, how can I return error messages from SQL and use these error messages in my rails app?

**e.g.** 
assume the **email** field is unique. and for making it unique, I just use `add_index :table_name, :column_name, unique: true`

```
User.create(name: "John", email: "john@gmail.com")
User.create(name: "Sofia", email: "john@gmail.com")    # it should returns an error
```

How can I get that error message and use it in my rails app?

Comment: Why is it so bad to have the validation on your model?

Comment: It does a query to validate

Answer (score 0):

To have `uniqueness` done right in Rails way you need to have validation in model and index in database.

Just add `validates :name, uniqueness: true` and you will be fine.

There could be still some rarely cases when you get SQL error message instead of  ActiveRecord error because of race condition.

More info: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness

Answer (score 0):

If you need to rescue duplicate errors raised by SQL you can use [activerecord-rescue_from_duplicate](https://github.com/Shopify/activerecord-rescue_from_duplicate) gem.
Using this gem allows whether use rails validation or not.

But generally speaking, adding uniqueness validation in your models doesn't guarantee uniqueness until you add a unique db index
Check out this [thread](https://discuss.rubyonrails.org/t/validates-uniqueness-of-doesnt-really-guarantee-uniqueness/74398/9) as well.

Comment: that's fine. but I don't need it just for the uniqueness validation. I need all of the validation.
you know, I wanna handle all of the messages that have been returned from SQL, in my Rails app.

Comment: Then why not use active record validations?

Comment: it does another query for validation.
assume you wanna create a record. it does two queries.
one query for ```validation``` and one query for ```create```